# using openform after followhyperlink in ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am pretty new to access. I have two files and on a button click in onte of them the other form is opened:

```
Private Sub ComMA_Click()
FollowHyperlink "L:\Files\File.mdb"
End Sub
```

and it works perfectly.

But I want to open a specific form (Not the main form) of the second file with the button click. something like this:

```
Private Sub ComMA_Click()
FollowHyperlink "L:\Files\File.mdb"
(Then DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTest")
End Sub
```

Is that possible or make sense at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick. The problem you ran into is being able to reference the second database from the code in the first database. To do this, you need to create an Access app object and have that app open the file. Then you can call the app object to open the form in your second database.

Code from [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/open-form-in-another-database.3999128/)

```
Private Sub ComMA_Click()
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "L:\Files\File.mdb"
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTest"
Set appAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```